# Is it possible to play the same minecraft world on different devices?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that the new Minecraft on Windows is cross platform. I can play on Xbox and have a friend who's on his laptop join and another on his phone join as well.

My question is, if I created a world on the Xbox, is it possible that I continue playing that same world on my phone after I turn off the Xbox? I don't see any save file on the Xbox that I can copy or move.

Comment: There's no way to sync it from one to the other. You can obviously connect to your Xbox world from your phone (you didn't mention whether you had an iPhone or an android phone). It is possible to transfer your profile via USB drive from Xbox to Xbox so I imagine you could transfer the profile to your computer and from there you can transfer via a file manager to your android phone. Whether or not the profile is the same file is another question. I've only played the PC and Mac versions, so I'm not entirely sure what format it would be in.

Comment: I have moved a world from my Android to my Windows 10 Machine fully intact.  I don't have any rep here and can't post what I did to make it happen though.  I have posted a similar questions that expands on this premise --> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/350756/75980

Answer (score 2):

According to the Better Together update recently launched, it looks like you **can** use the same world on different devices as you describe it. 
[Microsoft did a news release on this](https://news.microsoft.com/en-gb/2017/09/22/minecraft-better-together-update-lets-start-console-keep-playing-mobile/) that indicates what you say you want to do is possible.

From what I know, you will probably need an Xbox live account to do this. I read this somewhere on Minecraft's official website.

Please tell me if this helped you. If it didn't, I'll do more research and edit this post.

Answer (score -1):

The best I could find is a world transfer from phone to PC:

But from some research done online it doesn't look like you can do what you asked.