# Can I point Devices to the same World Pool to pick up where I left off?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to be able to reference the same worlds from my Windows 10 Machine and my Android Devices.

I want to be able to play on my Computer in worlds:

1. A1
2. B5
3. B6

and be able to log off and go mobile in the Android App on the fly in the same set of worlds.

1. A1
2. B5
3. B6

Realms doesn't let you do this, Realms forces you to have one world online at a time, all the time.

I am looking to find a way to share a common folder for worlds in the cloud so I don't have to move them anywhere when I switch devices.

Is there a way to set the game so that it saves and loads from a cloud folder like Google Drive?

---

Regarding the linked [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321635/how-to-share-worlds-between-platforms-with-minecraft-better-together) raised as a duplicate:

That question focuses on moving one world from one platform to the next (and maybe back again). I am looking to find a way to share a common folder for world's in the cloud, so I *don't have to move them anywhere*. Hands off I can play any of my 10 world's on either platform, PC or Android.